# Force DNS server ip while connected to VPN

Tags: high-sierra, vpn, dns

I'm using Fortclient VPN to connect to a customer network and the client enforces the use of their DNS (since the customer is in Turkey I get false DNS responses on wikipedia and other websites while connected)
Before high sierra I was able to reset the DNS server used using `scutil`:

```
> d.init
> d.add ServerAddresses * 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
> set State:/Network/Service/forticlientsslvpn/DNS
```

that usually was enough, starting on high sierra even after setting the DNS value using `set` it still shows the old values:

```
> d.show
<dictionary> {
  ServerAddresses : <array> {
    0 : 8.8.8.8
    1 : 8.8.4.4
  }
}
> show State:/Network/Service/forticlientsslvpn/DNS
<dictionary> {
  ServerAddresses : <array> {
    0 : 192.168.20.10
    1 : 192.168.20.11
  }
}
> set State:/Network/Service/forticlientsslvpn/DNS
> show State:/Network/Service/forticlientsslvpn/DNS
<dictionary> {
  ServerAddresses : <array> {
    0 : 192.168.20.10
    1 : 192.168.20.11
  }
}
```

Is there another way to do it in High Sierra?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution, open source client [openfortivpn](https://github.com/adrienverge/openfortivpn) let you skip dns settings while connecting to the VPN. Using its `--no-dns --pppd-no-peerdns` options fixes it